# Number of inversions and length of a word in a symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $w$ be a reduced word in the symmetric group $S_n$. Is the number of inversions of $w$ equals to the length of $w$? I checked some small examples and this is true. Is it correct in general? Thank you very much.

Edit: the symmetric group $S_n$ consists of permutations on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. The   group $S_n$ are generated by simple reflections: $s_i=(i,i+1)$, $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$. A word in $S_n$ is a word in $s_i=(i,i+1)$, $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: What do you mean by a word? A word in what?

Comment: A "word" is not defined until you define the set of letters. Presumably you have some generating set in mind?

Comment: There are plenty of possible symmetric groups on words. Which one is it (elements of your group) and what is the operation of your group ?

Comment: In the edited version, the answer is yes. The number of inversions is precisely the length of an element when seen as an element in the Coxeter group with the usual set of generators. I don't have a reference handy, but I recall it being a not too hard induction proof on the length.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Out of curiosity, what other property does a word have to have to be reduced besides not having inverses next to each other? (Or is it possible "all reduced word for the same element have the same length" is true for the free group, not necessarily for quotients thereof like the symmetric group?)

Comment: @arctictern It has to be of shortest length possible. This is equivalent to there *never* being the same simple reflection twice in a row even when one can rearrange the letters using the braid relations.

Comment: (note that these terms need some extra structure to be well-defined, in this case the fact that this is a Coxeter group).

Answer (score 3):

Yes the number of inversions of $w$ equals the length of $w$ when $S_n$ is viewed as a Coxeter Group with the simple reflections $s_i = (i,i+1)$ as a generating set. This is Proposition 1.5.2 in Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups by Bjorner, Brenti.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the definition of [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(group_theory)) as a product of elements of the symmetric group (the set of all permutations on a set of n elements) and "number of inversion" as the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) this said product would lead to if $S_n$ operates on a non-cyclically ordered set, the answer is no.

Take the word $w_1 = a_1 a_2 a_3$. It has the length 3 and some number of inversions. Now define $b = a_2 a_3$. $w_2 = a_1 b$ has the length 2 but still the same number of inversions.

Comment: Maybe you happened to try only with different transpositions as they generate $S_n$.

Comment: The question clearly stated what generating set is used (the standard one).